# Is any other android devices having Leanback feature except AndroidTV?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

Is any other android devices having Leanback feature except AndroidTV?

I want to restrict my app on play store only for Android TV.
So, i have added this to manifest

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />
```

[from "https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html#Declare Leanback support"](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html#Declare%20Leanback%20support)

Is it right way to restrict only for AndroidTV on play store?

Answer (score 3):

> Declare that your app uses the Leanback user interface required by Android TV. If you are developing an app that runs on mobile (phones, wearables, tablets, etc.) as well as Android TV, set the required attribute value to false. If you set the required attribute value to true, your app will run only on devices that use the Leanback UI.

The way I interpret this, I would say this limits the app to only TV.

Comment: plus1 for your answer but this is not complete answer

Comment: What do you want to know further?

Comment: Is any other android devices having Leanback feature except AndroidTV?

Comment: Is it right way to restrict only for AndroidTV on play store?

Comment: What about first question?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no

Comment: @Test_Me Amazon FireTV device in which we can use the LeanBack API's